# What is difference between svn Merge b1 b2 Or simple patching b2 with b1?

Tags: svn, version-control, merge, diff, patch

**Problem:**

Here:

```
b1 = svn branch 1
b2 = svn branch 2
```

I am not able to understand the difference in :

1. If I merge a `branch b1` with `branch b2`
2. If I create a patch by diffing `b1 and b2` using tool like meld or beyond compare, and then apply that patch on `b2`

Is that exactly same / similar ?

If yes, then why is that I can do `step 2` offline [ Without internet ] and `step 1` can only be done online with `svn merge` ?

**Please explain !!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example showing the fundamental difference between diffing and merging (we are not even talking about SVN):

Suppose you have a file F both in b1 and b2. F has an extra line in b1, but not in b2. Diffing will give you a different result depending on whether you `diff b1/F b2/F` or `diff b2/F b1/F`. In one case it will tell you that the line was deleted, in the other - that it was added. So which patch are you going to apply?

Merge (even if it a regular no-svn merge) is done relative to the 3rd source - usually the common ancestor. Then you usually can tell if the line was added or deleted - if it is in the ancestor it was deleted, if not - added.

In other words, merging is applying changes from *both* b1 and b2. Simple diffing can't know what changes took place - there is no 3rd source.

Now, if you do have the common source as well - you can achieve the result similar to svn merge. You can even argue that sometimes SVN is a real pest by screaming that you have a conflict when the exact same change was applied to both branches. Theoretically one can come with examples when offline merge won't give you the right result, they mostly apply to not recognizing conflicts. Besides SVN does some useful bookeeping of merges.

So if absolutely necessary, you can do this: keep a copy of the common source b; when you need to merge b1 into b2: `diff b1 b` and apply the patch to b2.

Better yet (as I mentioned previously) use Git or Mercurial.

Comment: I want to use `GIT` - But my company uses svn. Anyways that is not important.

If identical files cause conflict on svn and not on patching - So, that is a side-effect of svn rather something useful.

Anyways.. so the output of `step 1` and `step 2`, will there be any difference at all ?

Does svn knows about merges ? I mean does svn knows that a merge happened or are the changes are simply changes which were committed ?

Comment: Yes, they may be different: b1==b (the original), a line is deleted in b2. Diffing b1 and b2 and patching b2 puts that line back! But it is not what you want. The merge will keep the line deleted. Also SVN does know that the merge happened, but only if you do `svn merge`, not 'outside' merge.

Comment: How does svn knows that a merge happened.. ? Even if it does even then, does that matter ?
Since we can revert the changes in either case. [ Merged / Patched ]
So.. how does that info helps ?

Comment: It worth noting that `svn merge` since some version (1.5?) records the merged URL and the range of revisions in a special property, `svn:mergeinfo` which allows Subversion to track what was already merged and thus facilitate what's called "reintegration" -- when developments done on a branch are periodically merged into some other branch, because Subversion is able to know the "merge base" by looking at `svn:mergeinfo`.

Comment: @kostix, that's the main thing that I meant by "useful  bookkeeping", but I did not want to stray too much from the original question. Thank you for spelling it out. Yugal, please read [the section on merges in Version Control with Subversion](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.branchmerge.html). Maybe there is a better source that explains SVN merging (it took me a couple of months before I felt sufficiently comfortable with it). But all the information is there.